# Querying IP fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have many documents in an index, and each document has a field called "ip" which is of type "ip".

I'm trying to get only the documents whos IP ends with 0.

I wrote this

```
{
  "query": 
  {
    "regexp": 
    {
      "ip": "[0-255].[0-255].[0-255].0"
    }
  }
}
```

But apparently it's not possible to run regexp on IP type fields. Range query does work, but doesn't help for what we are trying to achieve.

How do I write this query?

Comment: We're you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with `ip` type.

If you are allowed to do alter mapping, You could use [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html#multi-fields) - one with ip representation and another with `raw` notation where you can use `regex` queries.